# Xcode organiser validation issue

Tags: ios, xcode, validation, frameworks, archive

i had an issue when i validating archived app.
I have already tried to change the bundle id, the newsstand icon. But it still displayed same issue.
this is the screenshot [issue screenshot http://imageshack.com/a/img10/8295/k8uv.png](http://imageshack.com/a/img10/8295/k8uv.png)

I using baker framework to create magazine app.
Anybody can help me? Thanks.

Comment: once more check your bundle identifire (same as previous version)

Comment: thanks Midhun for displaying the image :)
I checked so many times. It still same issue. i have 2 bundle id.for example this app i want use com.budle.baker, the second bundle id is com.budle.coconut. why it always displaying com.budle.coconut? i change bundle id in info.plist to com.budle.baker and nothing solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After I replace info.plist file, The Bundle identifier issue is gone now. But the Missing icon file is still there. I search in baker framework forum, they have same issue, I using baker 4.2. They updated to 4.2.2. After I downloaded it and verify, the issue now passed all.
Thanks to Mani and Maniganda Saravanan for your respond :)

UPDATE: The first error is caused I haven't set it to "Ready to upload binary" in iTunes Connect. I don't know it must clicked before validate an app in xCode

Answer (score 0):

Check the Bundle Identifier in projectname-info.plist is same as the previous version then 
1. clean the project,
2. close the xcode,
3. open it and then run.

Answer (score 0):

Following points need to be consider for your errors.

1. You cann't change your bundle id's after first version of your app.
   See the last of point of [About Bundle IDs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/ConfiguringYourApp/ConfiguringYourApp.html) topic in `apple
   docs`.
2. You must list out icon files in info.plist as [App Icons on iPad and
   iPhone](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1686/_index.html)

Comment: what do you mean first version? can we change bundle id in info.plist?

Comment: did you read that document? While you put your app in app store, what was the bundle id? that's first version's bundle id which won't change later.

Comment: i have read it. yes that is bundle id. but i have submit any app in App Store so i can change the bundle id right?

Comment: Simple question man. Did you submit this app already on app store or Is this first time? and check with this statement form apple's doc`ensure that every bundle ID is unique`

Comment: sorry i miss to type "haven't"